# How to get decode this attachment filename with python?

Tags: python, decode, email-attachments, email-headers

I already decoded a lot of email attachments filenames in my code.

But this particular filename breaks my code.

Here is a minimal example:

```
from email.header import decode_header
encoded_filename='=?UTF-8?B?U2FsZXNJbnZvaWNl?==?UTF-8?B?LVJlcG9ydC5wZGY=?='
decoded_header=decode_header(encoded_filename) # --> [('SalesInvoiceQ1|\x04\xb5I\x95\xc1\xbd\xc9\xd0\xb9\xc1\x91\x98', 'utf-8')]
filename=str(decoded_header[0][0]).decode(decoded_header[0][1])
```

Exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 16: invalid start byte
```

Don't ask my how, but Thunderbird is able to decode this filename to: `SalesInvoice-Report.pdf`

How can I decode this with python like email clients apparently are able to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **two** [*Encoded-Word*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) sections in that header. You'd have to detect where one ends and one begins:

```
>>> print  decode_header(encoded_filename[:28])[0]
('SalesInvoice', 'utf-8')
>>> print  decode_header(encoded_filename[28:])[0]
('-Report.pdf', 'utf-8')
```

Apparently that's what Thunderbird does in this case; split the string into `=?encoding?data?=` chunks. **Normally** these should be separated by `\r\n` (CARRIAGE RETURN + LINE FEED) characters, but in your case they are mashed up together. If you re-introduce the `\r\n` separator the value decodes correctly:

```
>>> decode_header(encoded_filename[:28] + '\r\n' + encoded_filename[28:])[0]
('SalesInvoice-Report.pdf', 'utf-8')
```

You could use a regular expression to extract the parts and re-introduce the separator:

```
import re
from email.header import decode_header

quopri_entry = re.compile(r'=\?[\w-]+\?[QB]\?[^?]+?\?=')

def decode_multiple(encoded, _pattern=quopri_entry):
    fixed = '\r\n'.join(_pattern.findall(encoded))
    output = [b.decode(c) for b, c in decode_header(fixed)]
    return ''.join(output)
```

Demo:

```
>>> encoded_filename = '=?UTF-8?B?U2FsZXNJbnZvaWNl?==?UTF-8?B?LVJlcG9ydC5wZGY=?='
>>> decode_multiple(encoded_filename)
u'SalesInvoice-Report.pdf'
```

Of course, it *could* be that you have a bug in how you read the header in the first place. Make sure you don't accidentally destroy an existing `\r\n` separator when extracting the `encoded_filename` value.

Comment: I gave you a bounty for "Reward existing answer". Thank you very much! ... needs 23 hours ... strange restriction of Stackoverflow.

Comment: @guettli: thank you! You didn't really have to, but it is *much* appreciated. The restrictions are in place to combat fraud. If you could immediately award the community would not get a chance to audit bounties used to transfer rep for nefarious purposes. And look at it this way: the extra attention over the bounty period *can* result in extra upvotes, and perhaps someone knows an even better solution to the problem. :-)

Comment: BTW, we already parsed several thousand file names in mail headers. I guess the client creates the broken encoding.

Comment: @guettli: yes, if a client is producing those headers *without* a CRLF in between then that's a broken client. It could also be that it produces the value with a line separator (correct or somehow malformed) and that a MTA in between then 'repairs' the value, etc. Either way, you now have to deal with the fall-out.